# access VBA error "operation not supported for this type of object"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this vba code and I don't understand why it return error
me.ID is stored as string btw

```
Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Me.ID = UCase(Me.ID)
      Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Products")   
    rs.FindFirst ("[SKU] =""" & Me.ID & """") //this is the one giving error
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox ("SKU Existed")
        Me.ID.Value = Null
        Me.Next.SetFocus //just for the sake of moving to this field then
        Me.ID.SetFocus  //to this field coz sometimes it won't go straight to
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing End Sub
```

[image: any idea where I got this wrong ?]

Comment: What's `Me.Next` and why are you setting focus to it if you're going to set focus to `Me.ID` immediately after.

Comment: What line of code throws the error? What have you tried to fix it?

Comment: I've tried to create a string just to simplify .FindFirst  
other than that I don't know where I got it wrong

Comment: Strange. An obvious error are the parentheses, these should only be used if you want a function/method to return a parameter, and should be removed both on that `rs.FindFirst` and that `MsgBox`, but I haven't seen it cause this error. You can specify `dbOpenDynaset` on the `.OpenRecordset`, but that should be the default.

Comment: well you know what Erik, I actually specify `dbOpenDynaset` and it work. strange, I always thought that is the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.OpenRecordset("<a local Table>")
```

will open a recordset of type `Table`, for which `.FindFirst` etc. are not valid.

Either use `dbOpenDynaset` or use the [`.Seek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836416.aspx) method.

[Database.OpenRecordset Method (DAO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx)

> If you open a Recordset in a Microsoft Access workspace and you don't specify a type, OpenRecordset creates a table-type Recordset, if possible. If you specify a linked table or query, OpenRecordset creates a dynaset-type Recordset.