# Extracting values in table using VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking for a LM500 in  a table "tblEngineFamilies" with two columns. table has 6 rows

```
Col 1: EFID
Col 2: EF
```

Below is the code i'm working out

```
Public Sub TestTableSearch()

Dim rstTable As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset

Set rstTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblEngineFamilies")

rstTable.Filter = "EF = 'LM500'"
```

Error msg: Operation is not supported for this type of object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access VBA error "operation not supported for this type of object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51283348/access-vba-error-operation-not-supported-for-this-type-of-object)

Comment: I'm facing compile error : Invalid use of Me keyword

Comment: You haven't used the `Me` keyword anywhere, so that's hard to believe. If there's a different issue elsewhere in your code, please share. While Gustav's answer is valid, this just is a duplicate. you can try `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEngineFamilies WHERE EF = 'LM500'"")` to immediately open a filtered recordset.

Comment: Hi Erik i'm trying with below code but showing the compile error

Code:
Public Sub TestTableSearch()

Dim rstTable As Recordset
Dim rst1 As Recordset

Set rstTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEngineFamilies WHERE EF = 'LM500'"")

rstTable.Filter = "EF = 'LM500'"

Compile Error:
Expected: list separator or )

Answer (score 0):

For such simple tasks, use *DLookup*:

```
FoundEFID = DLookup("[EFID]", "tblEngineFamilies", "[EF] = 'LM500'")
```